# What is Marshal and unmarshal in Golang Proto?

Tags: go, proto

I understand that we need to marshall object to serialise it, and unMarshall to deserialise it. However my question is, when do we invoke marshal and unmarshal and why do we serialise the objects if we are going to deserialise it again soon?

PS I just started to learn Go and Proto so would really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: "*... deserialise it again soon*" - in another process, maybe on another machine. Otherwise there's no need for any proto, in the same process you can just pass the object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good question!

Marshaling (also called serializing) converts a struct to raw bytes. Usually, you do this when you're sending data to something outside your program: you might be writing to a file or sending the struct in an HTTP request body.

Unmarshaling (also called deserializing) converts raw bytes to a struct. You do this when you're accepting data from outside your program: you might be reading from a file or an HTTP response body.

In both situations, the program sending the data has it in memory as a struct. We have to marshal and unmarshal because the recipient program can't just reach into the sender's memory and read the struct. Why?

- Often the two programs are on different computers, so they can't access each other's memory directly.
- Even for two processes on the same computer, shared memory is complex and usually dangerous. What happens if you're halfway through overwriting the data when the other program reads it? What if your struct includes sensitive data (like a decrypted password)?
- Even if you share memory, the two programs need to interpret the data in the same way. Different languages, and even different versions of Go, represent the same struct differently in memory. For example, do you represent integers with the most-significant bit first or last? Depending on their answers, one program might interpret `001` as the integer `1`, while the other might interpret the same memory as the integer `4`.

Nowadays, we're usually marshaling to and unmarshaling from some standardized format, like JSON, CSV, or YAML. (Back in the day, this wasn't always true - you'd often convert your struct to and from bytes by hand, using whatever logic made sense to you at the time.) Protobuf schemas make it easier to generate marshaling and unmarshaling code that's CPU- and space-efficient (compared to CSV or JSON), strongly typed, and works consistently across programming languages.